# Div's size changing when scrolling on Firefox Mobile, but it doesn't have to. Angular

Tags: angular, firefox, sass

I am testing my Angular application on mobile devices. Everything works fine on Chrome and Safari, but when it comes to Firefox, I am facing an issue: when you scroll in Firefox, its toolbar and url bar appear and they actually take the screen space, making my div with an image change its size to adapt to a new screen size. On Chrome or Safari, the toolbar and url bar do not change screen size so my div stays the same. I am expecting the div to stay the same on all browsers, but I have no idea what can I do.

You can see how exactly my div behaves on scrolling in Firefox in this [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/jlUwIDTMwgI?feature=share).

home.component.scss:

```
.image-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5LMZnTlF35-RsejDKRDrjiApA6ggZjsXtH2yvKGBM&s) center/cover no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 100vh 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
}
```

I tried adding these global styles to solve div's size changing

```
body { 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
    overscroll-behavior: none; 
}
```

But it doesn't work...((

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using min-height: 100vh, which is a percentage of the height of the viewport's initial containing block ([mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh)). I changed container's height to 500px, which is a fixed value and now div doesn't change its size because of Firefox' url bar and toolbar. It's kind of silly, but if there is any better way, I would like to get a recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with 100vh. I recommend to you to visit this video about it. https://youtu.be/veEqYQlfNx8

You can find solution (again) on YT video. https://youtu.be/pOuE9sgK9jY

you can probably use `dvh` and `dvw`
https://caniuse.com/?search=dvh

Or if you are scary about it, you can use `@support` to check if this solution can be implemented.